# How to convert FROM sas date format TO int in postgres (Amazon redshift)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sas, amazon-redshift

Bear with me, because I don't have the vocab down. I am converting SAS dates to int using Navicat with postgresql. I have successfully used

```
DATEADD(day,round(field_name)::int,'19600101') -> where field_name = '-8705' stored 
as varchar(256)
```

for positive numbers, but this doesn't work for the negative numbers (pre Jan 1, 1960). Ideally, someone has a better/easier/more efficient way to convert from SAS dates, but I will be grateful for a way to convert these negative numbers to int. I have searched the Amazon Redshift documentation, and if the answer is in there I did not understand it. I learn best from examples, if possible.

This example seemed promising, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work for my situation:

```
SELECT total_days
 , CAST(end_date AS timestamp) t_stamp
 , CAST(end_date AS date) final_date_time
 -- date(end_date) will not work as end_date is date already
 , TO_CHAR(TRUNC(end_date), 'MM/DD/YYYY') final_date
FROM(
SELECT ROUND(1344444527/60/60/24)         total_days
    , TO_DATE('01-01-1960','dd-mm-yyyy') start_date
    , TO_DATE('01-01-1960','dd-mm-yyyy')+ (1344444527/60/60/24) end_date
 FROM dual
)
```

Thanks, in advance, for your help!!

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Do you get the wrong result or an error?

Comment: Added the SAS-tag, sunce this basically is a sas issue. BTW please add a sample of your input data (or is it a sas dataset?)

Comment: What do your SAS dates look like, without any processing?

Comment: It was returning the data in the original format, but I ran it again to check and now it's working. I have no idea why it wasn't working originally. Probably user error. Thank you for the comments though!!

Comment: Why would you want to convert it to an int? Store it as a date so you can use all the Postgres date operators and functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was returning the data in the original format, but I ran it again to check and now it's working. I have no idea why it wasn't working originally. Probably user error. Thank you for the comments though!!